# R inline compilation of C code fails on Windows

Tags: c, windows, r, line

Within the Windows XP Pro RGui, can't compile inline C code. Get error:
   **'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command**

Clearly there is a configuration error, but can't find a way to resolve it either in R documentation or via googling. Must be a simple solution!

The same R code works fine on linux: the inline C compiles and runs correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the RTools collection as described in detail in [Appendix D of the R Installation and Administration](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#The-Windows-toolset) manual.

Comment: Thanks, but that appendix deals with creating R packages. I do NOT want to do that, just want to use cfunction() to create inline C code.

Comment: You still need the same toolchain.

Comment: Indeed, you are right. That, plus manual fixes to the PATH and copying cygwin1.dll to the RTools\bin folder, has me up and running. Thanks!!!!!