# Adding vector elements with condition in R

Tags: r, performance, sum, conditional-statements, addition

Suppose I have a vector of elements that I want to add:

```
a <- c(1,2,-7,5)
```

Here are some additional test cases:

```
a <- c(1,2,-3,5)
a <- c(1,2,-7,-3,5)
```

I know I can use `sum(a)` to get the result, but what if I had a condition to watch out for:

```
current_sum = 0
for(i in 1:length(a)){    
 last_sum = current_sum
 current_sum = current_sum + a[i]
 if(current_sum < 0)
 {
  current_sum = last_sum
  current_sum = current_sum + (a[i]*-1)
 }
}
```

Here, each time the sum is negative, we go back to the previous sum and add the opposite of that number that made the sum go negative. Outputting 15 as a result of the first example

Obviously, the vector of elements is not known before hand and performance is of issue. Is there any fully vectorized method or a more efficient way to do this in general (avoiding loops) ?

Comment: How do you get `5 as a result` from what you described? Do you mean 15?

Comment: @xxfelixxx now suppose I had this vector a <- c(1,2,-3,5) using abs I would get 11 however I am expecting 5

Comment: @thelatemail you are right, I forgot the 1 before the 5. I fixed it

Comment: @Imlerith - just `sum(a)` works for that case.

Comment: @thelatemail that's why I specified "the vector of elements is not known before hand"

Comment: I think it's something like `sum(ifelse(cumsum(a) < 0, -a, a))`, though that's not robust.

Comment: @alistaire - you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @alistaire Actually, it doesn't work for certain cases. I added more test cases to my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find the R/C interface very useful for the tasks in which performance is important, there isn't an obvious vectorized R solution and the code in C is very easy to write. Try this:

```
require(inline)
.internalSumPositive<-cfunction(sig=c(v="SEXP"), language="C", body="
   double sum=0.0;
   int i,n = length(v);
   double *values = REAL(v);
   SEXP ret = PROTECT(allocVector(REALSXP,1));
   for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
      sum += values[i];
      if (sum<0) sum = sum - 2*values[i];
   }
   REAL(ret)[0] = sum;
   UNPROTECT(1);
   return ret;")

sumPositive<-function(v) {
   if (!is.numeric(v)) stop("Argument must be numeric")
   if (length(v)==0) return(numeric(0))
   .internalSumPositive(as.numeric(v))
}
```

Then you can try:

```
sumPositive(c(1,2,-7,5))
#[1] 15
sumPositive(c(1,2,-3,5))
#[1] 5
sumPositive(c(1,2,-7,-3,5))
#[1] 12
```

I won't report benchmark since it's not even a contest with the other proposed R solutions (this can be *tens of thousands* times faster).

Comment: That's really neat, and quite a cohesive example of how to use C from within R. As someone who knows nowt about anything like C, I am going to be stealing this as a template. So.... thanks!

Comment: I like the idea of writing code in C. But why does a loop written in C within R would achieve better performance than a loop within R ? Does R translate everything to C ?

Comment: I don't know what is happening in there. I am not familiar with this type of coding. Maybe one day I will. Hats off to you.

Comment: @nicola does this code requires any additional packages? i'm getting compilation errors

Comment: @Imlerith If you are on Windows you might miss the compilation tools. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442305/r-inline-compilation-of-c-code-fails-on-windows

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
f1 <- function(x) repeat{pos<-min(which(cumsum(x)<0))
                    x[pos]<-abs(x[pos])
                    if(all(cumsum(x)>=0)){return(sum(x));break}}
a <- c(1,2,-7,-3,5)
f1(a)
#[1] 12
```

Comment: for a <- c(1 ,2,-3 ,5) I got : Warning message:
In min(which(cumsum(x) < 0)) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf

Comment: Yeah. I know that. But, still that is returning correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try out `Reduce`, which can collapse a vector with a binary function:

```
a <- c(1,2,-7,5)
Reduce(function(x, y){x + ifelse(x + y < 0, -y, y)}, a)
## [1] 15

a <- c(1,2,-3,5)
Reduce(function(x, y){x + ifelse(x + y < 0, -y, y)}, a)
## [1] 5

a <- c(1,2,-7,-3,5)
Reduce(function(x, y){x + ifelse(x + y < 0, -y, y)}, a)
## [1] 12
```

Comment: I like this answer too, didn't know about the reduce function